# SVG Transformations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, translation, transform, transformation

SVG Transformations can be done through JavaScript by settings their corresponding attributes `setAttribute("transform", "translate(x,y)")` but should also be possible through *pure* JavaScript.

```
elem.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setTranslate(x, y);
elem.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setRotate(x, y);
```

These two should work for translation and rotation, but how about skewing, scaling and matrix? `elem.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix()` exists, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't excepts any params and `SVGCreateMatrix()` does not accept any params either. How am I supposed to do this, and as a bonus question: what does `getItem(0)` actually do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Each `<svg>` element has a [createSVGMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGMatrix) dom method.

```
var matrix = svgElement.createSVGMatrix();
```

This is the identity matrix.

You can then [manipulate this](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix)...

```
matrix = matrix.translate(10, 10);
```

or directly...

```
matrix.a = 3;
```

and then use it

```
elem.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(matrix);
```

[getItem(0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransformList) gets the first element in a transform attribute e.g.

```
transform="translate(1, 1) scale(2)"
```

`getItem(0)` gets the `translate(1, 1)` matrix and `getItem(1)` gets the `scale(2)` matrix

If you haven't set a transform on an element then `getItem(0)` will throw. You can check how many items there are using `numberOfItems` and/or add an initial item using `createSVGTransformFromMatrix` to turn your matrix into a transform and `appendItem` to append the transform.