# Change co-ordinate of text transform at matrix in SVG

Tags: svg

I am very new in SVG. Now, i am working on the text in SVG.

if the matrix is in the form *(1 0 0 1 286.6445 563.3346)*, then i assume x as 286.6445 and y as 563.3346

my problem is that, some times matrix found in another format *(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 304.2636 584.46)* like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 595 842" enable-background="new 0 0 595 842" xml:space="preserve">

<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 127.3852 556.6279)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shLUC </text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 158.0637 556.791)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shH2AX</tspan><tspan x="4.7" y="8.4" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">no.1 </tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 194.4885 556.791)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shH2AX</tspan><tspan x="3.8" y="8.4" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">no. 2 </tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 151.938 492.3261)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">Senescence </text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 93.7368 492.0358)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Bold'" font-size="8">f</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 227.0126 507.0358)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Bold'" font-size="8">g</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 289.2609 582.4389)"><tspan x="0" y="0" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">s</tspan><tspan x="3.5" y="0" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">hLU</tspan><tspan x="16.3" y="0" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">C</tspan></text>
<text transform="matrix(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 304.2636 584.46)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shH2AX</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 307.2189 591.7231)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shLUC + Cis</text>
<text transform="matrix(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 323.3571 593.1634)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">shH2AX + Cis</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 286.6445 563.3346)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">0</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 282.7241 544.9635)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">20</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 282.7241 526.5885)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">40</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 282.7241 508.2213)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">60</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 282.7241 489.8473)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue-Roman'" font-size="7">80</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 311.1016 504.7193)" font-family="'Symbol'" font-size="7">*</text>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 347.4725 481.9498)" font-family="'Symbol'" font-size="7">*</text>
</svg>
```

I need to extract the text from this SVG with corresponding co-ordinates. Almost all the matrix starts with "1 0 0 1", but some are different.

is there any logic/calculation to convert *(0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 304.2636 584.46)* into this format *(1 0 0 1 ? ?)*

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242137). Please illustrate your problem with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and perhaps someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: A (0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 304.2636 584.46) is a rotation and a transform. A (1 0 0 1 ? ?) is just a transfom. You can't do a rotation with a (1 0 0 1 ? ?) matrix. Each matrix represents a unique transform so you can't convert matrix a to matrix b it's like saying can I convert an apple to an orange in such a way that it remains an apple.

Comment: *"I need to extract the text from this SVG with corresponding co-ordinates"* — You want to extract text with coordinates corresponding to *what*, exactly? Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Robert Longson, Is it possible to take  value of rotate from the matrix a (like 20,40,60..) and then convert a to b. because i want the exact x,y.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810948/svg-transformations-in-javascript/16811570#16811570

Comment: thanks for the link. Could you tell the angle of this matrix (0.8191 -0.5736 0.5735 0.8192 304.2636 584.46).