# How to construct svg transform matrix

Tags: javascript, svg

SVG objects can have attribute `transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"` (values are example).
What is the best practice to construct this matrix? Concatinating strings here
seems just not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here
[SVG Transformations in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810948/svg-transformations-in-javascript)

```
var matrix = svgElement.createSVGMatrix();
matrix = matrix.translate(10, 10);
matrix.a = 3;
elem.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: You'd actually have to have a transform here otherwise getItem(0) will throw a range error.