# how to manipulate a svg matrix with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

how can I simply access a svg element, read the matrix and execute the rotation or transformation on the matrix objec.

I read the matrix from the element

```
let matrix = elements[index].getAttribute('transform');
```

I got

```
matrix(1 0 0 1 513.1588 411.1249)
```

Now I want to add something to the x value, and pass this transformation to anaother element.

```
 newElement.setAttribute('transform',matrix);
```

how can i make an matrix object to manipulate?

edited:
I tried the var matrix = svgElement.createSVGMatrix()´(posted below) but I can't access simple  elements. Like I understand the API, the createSVGMatrix is used for  elements

Comment: Does this answer your question: [SVG Transformations in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810948/svg-transformations-in-javascript/16811570#16811570)